# Is there an "Over-flowing Cup" in D&D?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

I am running a game in which there is a player character that is basically a functioning alcoholic. I have made a special rule that requires them to be above a certain level of inebriated to function normally, and if they fall below that level, they get withdrawals, hangovers, etc; which affects their ability to function normally.

For the most part, this is working well. It makes for interesting gameplay, however there has been a few situations where the player has left the party to go "refill", by simply hanging out in the bar for a few hours, while the rest of the party continue whatever they are doing. This has led to the player missing out on a few interesting situations.

This is where I came up with an idea - give the player a flask (or something similar) that can be filled with a liquid of their choice, that either

1. Holds a large amount of fluid (enough to last a *long* time)
2. Never empties

This way the player has to go for fewer "pit-stops" to refill their tankard.

Is there any items like this in D&D? And if so, how rare are they?

(For the record, I am using the 5e system, but if this item exists within other editions I'm open to it).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

## Alchemy Jug

The **Alchemy Jug** is an uncommon wondrous item.

> You can use an action and name one liquid from the table below to cause the jug to produce the chosen liquid. Afterward, you can uncork the jug as an action and pour that liquid out, up to 2 gallons per minute. The maximum amount of liquid the jug can produce depends on the liquid you named.

The specifics are in the DMG on page 150.

I believe this is the closest thing to what you are asking for.

Comment: Plus you get the added benefit of 2 gallons of mayonnaise if you have an emergency need.

Comment: @CharlieHorse I stopped counting how many characters I lost because they didn't have a jar of mayonnaise at hand when they needed it.

Comment: Not actually an answer but this came to mind: https://limey.net/~magnum/DL/Portable%20Hole%20Full%20of%20beer.pdf

Comment: Petition to reverse the quantities of oil and vinegar so I only have to wait two days to dress the 45 lbs of salad my cleric created with Conjure Food and Water ([recipe link](https://www.simplyrecipes.com/recipes/the_vinaigrette_ratio/))

Answer (score 19):

In Hoard of the Dragon Queen, pg 74 there is a Tankard of Plenty.

> The Golden Tankard takes its name from a magic item that Raggnar found years ago: a golden stein decorated with dancing dwarves and grain patterns. This is a tankard of plenty. Speaking the command word (“Illefarn”) while grasping the handle fills the tankard with three pints of rich dwarven ale. This power can be used up to three times per day.

Comment: Which edition is this? And can I find it in a DMG?

Comment: @Ben HotDQ is one of the big adventure campaigns for 5e, and it's not in the DMG.

Comment: Whoever wrote that was not a Dwarf. I sort of refuse to believe that any dwarf would consider 3 pints of Ale 3 times per day "Plenty". Raggnar was not an elf of some sort?

Comment: @TomTom, Raggnar appears to be a human.

Comment: @yinzanat Pathetic. Definitely from one of the weaker cultures that have no appreciation of what a proper amount of beer is.

Answer (score 17):

I think you're looking for the *Alchemy Jug*, which produces four gallons of beer per day. You could also get some mileage out of a *bag of holding* or *portable hole* with a bunch of wineskins in it.

But more generally, it sounds like your problem is you've decided the character needed to split off from the group for a few hours, and as a consequence they missed out on some action. The solution is to stop deciding that. There are no rules for how drunk a character is; if you think the character doesn't need to slip away (because he's not that sober yet, or because he can grab a beer to-go, etc), nobody's going to complain. Never let roleplaying get in the way of fun!

Comment: For the record, if I didn't make it clear, I'm the GM in this, not the player. Though this is still good advice - we made the rule to add to gameplay, but the player is finding it more of a crutch than anything; hence the habits.

Comment: @Ben I think the answer still stands - "you've decided [the] character needed to split off from the group for a few hours [...] The solution is to stop deciding that. [...] Never let roleplaying get in the way of fun!"

Answer (score 13):

Besides the options available in 5e, earlier editions all have variations on this, though they usually cap the uses per day and/or volume so that wiseacre players don't use it to generate infinite flammable liquid, etc.

For 3.5e there's the "Everfull Mug" (Magic Item Compendium) that costs 200 gp and does "Three times per day, when you recite the command word, this mug fills with 12 ounces of water, cheap ale, or watery wine (your choice)."

Pathfinder has variants on this that have various other kewl powerz, from the [Tankard of the Drunken Hero](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/tankard-of-the-drunken-hero) up to the [Drinking Horn of Bottomless Valor](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/c-d/drinking-horn-of-bottomless-valor). Just in case you're looking for sweet magic items he might want as upgrades later in his career.

In AD&D, there was the Mug of Plenty (Encyclopedia Magica, originally Moonshae FR supplement) that was worth 5000 gp and fills with light or dark ale or thick mead on command, no limit on uses.

It also had the Alchemy Jug (Encyclopedia Magica, originally DMG) - the glory of 5e is that it's an opportunity to recycle all the old stuff. 12000 gp, seven pourings a day, same deal with volume based on what the liquid is (4 gallons of beer/ale, for the record, just as in 5e).

The Cup of Wine (Encyclopedia Magica, originally Dragon 73) turned water into wine 1/day for 600 gp.

There's more I'm sure, but that should bracket you in on appropriate costs/usefulness combinations to roll your own.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, the Alchemy Jug.

You would probably be satisfied with the Alchemy Jug, a wondrous item found on pg 150 of the DMG. It has the ability to produce a number of named liquids, including 4 gallons of beer or 1 gallon of wine per day.

Comment: 1 gallon = 3.8 liters. That should do.

Comment: @JanDvorak I'm pretty sure I've drank more than a gallon of wine per day when I was alcoholic. The 4 gallons of beer might be okay, though.

Answer (score 6):

### An Ewer of Endless Wine

Just to supply another alternative to the very good *Alchemy Jug* and *Tankard of Plenty* answers, there a green copper ewer in the Curse of Strahd campaign that can keep a character supplied with alcohol.

It has a little more utility than the Tankard, but a bit less than the Jug.

> Any poisonous liquid poured into the ewer is instantly transformed into an equal amount of sweet wine. Furthermore, a creature that grasps the ewer's handle can command the ewer to fill with 1 gallon of wine, and it can't produce more wine until the next dawn.

It can be found:

> on page 188. In the Amber Temple, in room X22.

Answer (score 3):

Just to post a different answer:

If for some reason you don't like the alchemy jug, there's nothing wrong with a bag of holding filled with (preferably bottles of) alcohol.

Comment: DanB already suggested that, but it is certainly not a bad idea.